# "merging" multiple internet connections

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, dsl

I've seen this question asked several times here on SF, but I'm looking for some updated information; specifically concerning Server 2012.

I'm in the process of buying a home so I'm trying to get some plans together on how I want to structure my network. Internet speeds aren't the greatest and connections can be unreliable where the house is so I was thinking of having two DSL lines installed. My question is, how could I leverage those two connections to create the best network I can, in terms of speed and reliability. My parents will be moving in with me - they consume a lot of bandwidth as it is, but then add my internet traffic to it, and I'm headed for a lot of frustration.

I thought I remember reading somewhere that Server 2012 has some new functionality to utilize multiple connections on multiple NICs in a way that wasn't possible in earlier versions of Server.

Not sure if Windows will work but, I'm an application developer and spend the majority of my time in Windows environments. However, I've only recently returned to the Windows world, so I'd like my main server at home to run Win Server 2012 so that I can become more familiar with it.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Your question regarding a home network is off-topic here but would be perfect for Super User. I've recommended that it be moved so it won't be necessary to ask again over there. Refer to the [faq] for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this question may be migrated as it is off-topic here is what you're looking for:

This is a network level thing, its called `link aggregation`.  Essentially you take `1 + n` connections and make them appear to the rest of the intranet as a single connection.  While Windows may be able to do this in 2012 I wouldn't recommend it.  This task is pretty low-level on the network stack and usually a router or switch would handle the majority of the work.

There are multiple vendors who make products for this purpose.  Barracuda Networks has one, but its a bit large for the task.  Peplink also has a SOHO version.  Lastly, you may be able to get this working in DD-WRT as well but I am not exactly sure if thats possible or supported on all hardware.

[DD-WRT Round-Robin Load Balancing for WAN Connections](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Dual-WAN_for_simple_round-robin_load_equalization)

Comment: @Spencer, Look into a router with more than one WAN port.  There are many.  They will offer built-in tools as Brent suggested.  Personally, I use a Cisco RV042.  You might take a look at it to get you on the right track, but as I said, there are many.  Quick search at newegg for [Dual WAN Routers](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100010065%20600014494&IsNodeId=1&name=2%20x%2010%2f100Mbps)

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the suggestions, they were very helpful.